# tf.keras HDF5 Model and Keras HDF5 Model

Tags: keras, tensorflow-lite, tf.keras

I want to convert a Keras model to Tensorflow Lite model. When I examined the documentation, it is stated that we can use tf.keras HDF5 models as input. Does it mean I can use my saved HDF5 Keras model as input to it or tf.keras HDF5 model and Keras HDF5 models are different things?

Documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert

Edit: I could convert my Keras model to Tensorflow Lite model with using this API, but I didn't test it yet. My code:

```
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(path + 'plant- 
recognition-model.h5')
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('plant-recognition-model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: I suggest that you test your results and post an answer to your own question.

Comment: I'll do it, but it seems Tensorflow lite library provides very few features. I'm examining their examples to learn build my model,but in these examples even input images processed byte by byte. So it might take some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tf.keras HDF5 model and Keras HDF5 models are not different things, except for inevitable software version update synchronicity. [This is what the official docs say](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras):

> tf.keras is TensorFlow's implementation of the Keras API specification. This is a high-level API to build and train models that includes first-class support for TensorFlow-specific functionality

If the convertor can convert a keras model to tf.lite, it will deliver same results. But tf.lite functionality is more limited than tf.keras. If this feature set is not enough for you, you can still work with tensorflow, and enjoy its other advantages.

May be, it won't take too long before your models can run on a smartphone.

Comment: Thank you. If it deliver same results it is very good. Because when I searched how can I convert Keras models to tflite, results were mostly involved several steps. Converter should be a new feature. I chose tf.lite because I thought if I will run this model on mobile platform then using tf.lite is mandatory. I'm also considering to use DL4J.

Comment: As far as I can tell, tf.lite is not the only way to run on mobile; QNNPACK may be better for your needs, or Core ML if your target platform is iOS.

Comment: I didn't hear about QNNPACK, I'll look through it. My target is Android platform.

Comment: A colleague told me about https://pjreddie.com/darknet, but I did not dig deep enough into it

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.