# using keras h5 weights in tf.keras model

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have h5 weights from a Keras model.

I want to rewrite the Keras model into a tf.keras model (using TF2.x).

I know that only the high level API changed, but **do you know if I still can use the h5 weights?** 
Most likely they can be loaded, but is the structure different between Keras and tf.keras weights?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are the same

cudos to Mohsin hasan [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57482004/6510273)

> In the past, when I had to convert tf.keras model to keras model, I
>   did following:
>
> 1. Train model in `tf.keras`
> 2. Save only the weights `tf_model.save_weights("tf_model.hdf5")`
> 3. Make Keras model architecture using all layers in keras (same as the tf keras one)
> 4. load weights by layer names in keras: `keras_model.load_weights(by_name=True)`
>
> This seemed to work for me. Since, I was using out of box architecture
>   (DenseNet169), I had to very less work to replicate tf.keras network
>   to keras.

And the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55984420/6510273) from Alex Cohn

> tf.keras HDF5 model and Keras HDF5 models are not different things,
>   except for inevitable software version update synchronicity. This is
>   what the official docs say:
>
> > tf.keras is TensorFlow's implementation of the Keras API specification. This is a high-level API to build and train models that
> >     includes first-class support for TensorFlow-specific functionality
>
> If the convertor can convert a keras model to tf.lite, it will deliver
>   same results. But tf.lite functionality is more limited than tf.keras.
>   If this feature set is not enough for you, you can still work with
>   tensorflow, and enjoy its other advantages.